# how can we print transpose of a matrix in python?

Tags: python-3.x

First we have to take input of a matxix by asking number of rows and number of columns after that we have to display a message "enter the 1st row and 1st column" and for the next rows and next columns then we have to print its transpose(exchange rows with column and column with rows).

Transpose of matrix and printing it with the help of for loops.